# Exclude mysql table records that have matching, newer records

Tags: mysql

I have a system that queries a db table of game activity at various coordinates. I have a need to query for activities by a certain player but I need to exclude any that match newer entries at the same coordinates (by other players or not, just anything).

A sample query is:

```
SELECT * FROM prism_actions
WHERE world = 'world'
AND (action_type = 'block-place')
AND (player = 'viveleroi')
AND (x BETWEEN -448.7667627678472 AND -438.7667627678472)
AND (y BETWEEN 62.0 AND 72.0)
AND (z BETWEEN -291.17236958025796 AND -281.17236958025796)
ORDER BY x,y,z ASC
LIMIT 0,1000000
```

I've tried making it work with a subquery and inner join but just can't get it. I really need to be able to make this speedy as well.

Essentially I need this query to exclude any records at coords X,Y,Z when there's another record with same X,Y,Z but with a new action_time.

I've also considered some way of expiring records at the same x,y,z when a new match is entered but that seems not quite as efficient as I'd like as well.

Comment: Why did you tag this as 'java'?  Also, is there a primary key on this table?

Comment: Define "newer entries" according to your schema. Do you generate a timestamp/PK per new entry?

Comment: Java was just a tag because I'm running the queries from a java app, figured it may allow conversation outside of just mysql if possible. My table has a primary key, as well as timestamp (DATETIME) generated for every record.

Comment: What are the names of the primary-key and timestamp fields?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by joining on a subquery that filters out the 'latest' coordinates:

```
SELECT prism_actions.*
FROM prism_actions
JOIN (
    SELECT x, y, z, max(action_time) as action_time
    FROM prism_actions
    GROUP BY x, y, z) latest
  ON prism_actions.action_time = latest.action_time
  AND prism_actions.x = latest.x
  AND prism_actions.y = latest.y
  AND prism_actions.z = latest.z
WHERE prism_actions.world = 'world'
AND (prism_actions.action_type = 'block-place')
AND (prism_actions.player = 'viveleroi')
AND (prism_actions.x BETWEEN -448.7667627678472 AND -438.7667627678472)
AND (prism_actions.y BETWEEN 62.0 AND 72.0)
AND (prism_actions.z BETWEEN -291.17236958025796 AND -281.17236958025796)
ORDER BY x,y,z ASC
LIMIT 0,1000000
```

Comment: I've been running tests with this solution and it appears to be working perfectly. Thanks!