# MySQL Exluding newer records with a join a performance kill

Tags: mysql

I query a MySQL table for events that were recorded for specific x/y/z coordinates (for a game plugin, fyi). This query was written with a right join to exclude records that have *newer* entries at the exact same coordinates.

However, it's a performance kill.

For example, one query returns around 32k results (they normally won't be this high but I need to address the underlying issue) - *without* the right join comparison it takes: 33373 rows in set (0.19 sec).

With the right join it takes 32955 rows in set (3 min 7.99 sec)

3 minutes is way too long.

Here is an example query that includes the right join:

```
SELECT prism_actions.id, prism_actions.action_time, prism_actions.action_type, prism_actions.player, prism_actions.world, prism_actions.x, prism_actions.y, prism_actions.z, prism_actions.data, DATE_FORMAT(prism_actions.action_time, '%c/%e/%y') display_date, DATE_FORMAT(prism_actions.action_time, '%l:%i%p') display_time
FROM prism_actions
RIGHT JOIN (SELECT action_type, x, y, z, max(action_time) as action_time FROM prism_actions GROUP BY action_type, x, y, z) latest 
ON prism_actions.action_time = latest.action_time
AND prism_actions.x = latest.x
AND prism_actions.y = latest.y
AND prism_actions.z = latest.z
AND prism_actions.action_type = latest.action_type
WHERE world = 'world'
AND (prism_actions.action_type = 'creeper-explode' OR prism_actions.action_type = 'entity-explode' OR prism_actions.action_type = 'tnt-explode' OR prism_actions.action_type = 'block-burn')
AND LEFT(prism_actions.action_type,5) != 'prism'
AND (prism_actions.x BETWEEN 2412.0286793077976 AND 2612.0286793077976)
AND (prism_actions.y BETWEEN -25.5 AND 174.5)
AND (prism_actions.z BETWEEN -2650.697295131335 AND -2450.697295131335)
ORDER BY prism_actions.action_time ASC, x ASC, z ASC, y ASC, id ASC
LIMIT 0,1000000
```

Without, is simply to remove the right join.

**So my questions are:**

- Is this the best way to handle excluding records that have newer entries?
- If so, is there something I can do to improve the performance?

The reason I use such a query is that my software needs the results ordered by the timestamp, but should always only know about the most recent activity at each x/y/z otherwise things conflict.

Table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `prism_actions` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `action_time` datetime NOT NULL,
  `action_type` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `player` varchar(16) NOT NULL,
  `world` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `x` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `y` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `z` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `data` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Explain results for very reduced area of the above query:

```
+----+-------------+---------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table         | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra                                        |
+----+-------------+---------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY     | <derived2>    | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 1870 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort | 
|  1 | PRIMARY     | prism_actions | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 1970 | Using where                                  | 
|  2 | DERIVED     | prism_actions | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 1970 | Using temporary; Using filesort              | 
+----+-------------+---------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------------------------------------------+
3 rows in set (0.04 sec)
```

Comment: Why are you using an OUTER JOIN?

Comment: Based on solutions given to an original question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14114432/exclude-mysql-table-records-that-have-matching-newer-records

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the following will work slightly better. Assuming it gives you the right answer, but DOESN'T much help performance, consider providing SHOW CREATE TABLE statements for the relevant tables, and post the output of an EXPLAIN on this query...

```
SELECT pa.id
     , pa.action_time
     , pa.action_type
     , pa.player
     , pa.world
     , pa.x
     , pa.y
     , pa.z
     , pa.data
     , DATE_FORMAT(pa.action_time, '%c/%e/%y') display_date
     , DATE_FORMAT(pa.action_time, '%l:%i%p') display_time
  FROM prism_actions pa 
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT action_type
            , x
            , y
            , z
            , MAX(action_time) max_action_time 
         FROM prism_actions 
        GROUP 
           BY action_type
            , x
            , y
            , z
     ) latest 
    ON latest.max_action_time = pa.action_time 
   AND pa.x = latest.x
   AND pa.y = latest.y
   AND pa.z = latest.z
   AND pa.action_type = latest.action_type
 WHERE world = 'world'
   AND pa.action_type IN('creeper-explode','entity-explode','tnt-explode','block-burn')
   AND pa.action_type NOT LIKE 'prism%'
   AND pa.x BETWEEN 2412.0286793077976 AND 2612.0286793077976
   AND pa.y BETWEEN -25.5 AND 174.5
   AND pa.z BETWEEN -2650.697295131335 AND -2450.697295131335
 ORDER 
    BY pa.action_time ASC
     , x ASC
     , z ASC
     , y ASC
     , id ASC
 LIMIT 0,1000000;
```

Comment: But this seems to do the opposite, it returns only records that are the newest for each coordinate, returning only 531 rows in set (0.10 sec).

Comment: So you want to return all results at a given coordinate EXCEPT for the newest one?

Comment: I may have confused myself on the query I need. This is for a rollback plugin for Minecraft servers. My notes say "if a player breaks a block, then places a new one at the same spot and breaks it again, we need the newest action to rollback - because we order actions by time the first block was always rolling back first. Maybe the plain JOIN is what I need, *but*, it took my results from 32k, which was accurate, down to 512. Maybe it must be: query for only the newest action at each coord but also include any that have no older entries?

Comment: I ran an experiment with the standard JOIN and it produces the correct results I need on a small scale. I've got someone testing this in more complex scenarios. Let me get back to you soon

Comment: Ok, so the join query works for me but overall the performance is still a big issue. A query with 3,200 results runs for 4 seconds with this join, without it they return in .13 seconds. I need to retain the ability to only query the most recent but I really need a faster method. This might help explain my need: http://pastie.org/private/yden4jtwxrh1ov9ffezwq

Comment: I don't know if this would work better, but maybe I should just run an UPDATE every time we record an action that invalidates older ones. That may not work for all my needs but it would at least offload work to the recording tasks and take away the performance issue on this query which is where it hurts.